# AngularJS application config file

Tags: angularjs

It's just a conceptual question as I'm writing my first app in AngularJS.

Is it a good idea / practice to embed some 'app wide' / 'global', constants / configs variables within a Angurar's service? - as it is singleton by definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Over than Angular app it is actually a good practice to externalize conf like parameters.

With Angular you can do it with "service" or "factory" functions. But the more appropriate is "constant" as it can be injected every where even in .config.

```
myApp.constant('CONF', function(){

  var YOUR_SERVER_CONSTANTS;

   // your declarations

  return YOUR_SERVER_CONSTANTS;

})
```